# How to evaluate PowerShell script inputed from stdin

Tags: powershell, stdin

I want to evaluate the content from StdIn in PowerShell, like this:

```
echo "echo 12;" | powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -command "$input | iex"
```

Output:

```
echo 12;
```

Unfortunately, `$input` is not a String, but a `System.Management.Automation.Internal.ObjectReader`, which make `iex` not working as expected... since this one is working correctly:

```
powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -command "$command = \"echo 12;\"; $command | iex"
```

Output:

```
12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following would work:

Use a scriptblock:

```
echo "echo 12;" | powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -command { $input | iex }
```

Or use single quotes to avoid the string interpolation:

```
 echo "echo 12;" | powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -command '$input | iex'
```

so the $input variable isn't expanded, and the string '$input' is passed to iex.

Both of these give me "12".

Comment: This is working when you're running this from another PowerShell, but it's not working when using it from cmd.exe. Why?

Comment: That's to do with the quotes around the "echo 12;". If you execute this in powershell echo "echo 12;" gives echo 12; without the quotes. In cmd.exe you'll see that it writes "echo 12;", which is then interpreted as a string by Powershell. To make it work in cmd.exe you can try: `echo echo 12; | powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -command "$input | iex"`

Answer (score 3):

Just use `-` as a source file "name":

```
echo "echo 12;" | powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -
```